# Random mongo shutdown

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I had mongo randomly shutdown on one of my servers today and I was wondering if anyone could take a look at the logs below and tell me what might have happened. The server is hosted on digital ocean but there seems to be a number of odd ip's trying to connect before the server went down.

```
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57440 #48 (7 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57441 #49 (8 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57442 #50 (9 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 06:42:13.027 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57443 #51 (10 connections now open)
Sun Jun 14 08:26:29.103 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 7ms
Mon Jun 15 04:56:19.810 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:44313 #52 (11 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 04:56:19.950 [conn52] end connection 184.105.247.195:44313 (10 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 04:56:40.737 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:52328 #53 (11 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 04:56:40.809 [conn53] end connection 184.105.247.195:52328 (10 connections now open)
Mon Jun 15 08:00:01.940 [conn50] remove scottwio.tweets ndeleted:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 1 locks(micros) w:181995 183ms
Tue Jun 16 02:22:39.000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 52.28.2.57:45022 #54 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 02:22:39.013 [conn54] end connection 52.28.2.57:45022 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 02:22:39.466 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 52.28.2.57:45039 #55 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 02:22:45.578 [conn55] end connection 52.28.2.57:45039 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:07:28.573 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 169.54.233.118:21188 #56 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:07:59.589 [conn56] end connection 169.54.233.118:21188 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:29.197 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:47712 #57 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:29.337 [conn57] end connection 184.105.247.195:47712 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:48.188 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 184.105.247.195:53870 #58 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 06:15:48.273 [conn58] end connection 184.105.247.195:53870 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:38.214 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 74.82.47.3:53219 #59 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:38.339 [conn59] end connection 74.82.47.3:53219 (10 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:56.436 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 74.82.47.3:60827 #60 (11 connections now open)
Tue Jun 16 21:20:56.505 [conn60] end connection 74.82.47.3:60827 (10 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:55958 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:55955 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:55954 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:55957 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 06:25:58.255 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:55956 (9 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn47] end connection 127.0.0.1:57439 (4 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn48] end connection 127.0.0.1:57440 (3 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn49] end connection 127.0.0.1:57441 (2 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.976 [conn50] end connection 127.0.0.1:57442 (2 connections now open)
Wed Jun 17 08:00:00.977 [conn51] end connection 127.0.0.1:57443 (2 connections now open)


***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=820 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=scottwio
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] git version: a350fc38922fbda2cec8d5dd842237b904eafc14
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.020 [initandlisten] options: { fork: true, logappend: true, logpath: "/root/Sites/logs/mongo" }
Wed Jun 17 08:50:26.031 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
```

Comment: The traffic from those IPs happened over 10 hours before it restarted. It's unlikely they had anything to do with with the server restart.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you run out of disk space or memory?